# Install fedora or ubuntu with nvidia graphics card enabled laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card

I am trying to install either fedora or ubuntu in a nvidia graphics card included laptop, my preference is fedora, but ubuntu will also do.

Laptop company is Sager, nvidia card in GEFORCE GTX, i7 processor. There is no option to disable the graphics card in bios menu.

I did some research and tried these:

Installed fedora 24 workstation from a netinstall image using a usb stick, after login the screen freezes.

Installed from a live image (without internet connection) of fedora 24 workstation using usb, it freezes at same point.

Installed above fedora version from a dvd, same result.

Tried all above with test media and install option, it freezes after "started user with pid 1000".

Tried to install from a ubuntu live image using usb, I selected try and install option, it freezes after 5 seconds on the ubuntu loading screen.

Please let me know if anything else I can try out, I am running out of options.

I saw some answers about how to install nvidia drivers with downloading rpm and install, but not sure how can I do that if I am not able to log in to the system.

I tried adding a 3 in the fedora boot menu in the line which starts with "linux", it started with terminal but internet connection is not there, tried wget, did not work.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Some additional details would help: exact model sager laptop, nvidia model number, and does it have optimus graphics - if so can you disable them?

Comment: @Argonauts, Sager laptop model: W650RC1, Nvidia model no. - GeForce GTX 950M GPU with 2GB GDDR5 Video Memory, it has optimus technology. I am not able to disable them brom bios, if you are aware of some other method please let me know. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers on your linux installation. I only know how to do this for Ubuntu, but the process should be similar for other operating systems.

-Install Ubuntu using the old interactive installer

-Boot. When the screen freezes, press ctrl+alt+F2 to go to a terminal. If this doesn't work, you'll have to use the shell in the installer disk to manually install the drivers. (Unfortunately, this is extremely difficult and out of my hands)

-Run `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

If this doesn't work, I recommend finding out the specific model of your GPU(Nvidia GTX is a line with a lot of graphics cards) and googling for problems with that card. You might not be the first to encounter this problem.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Anton, can you please redirect me to where I can find a ubuntu old interactive installer. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD should be the right thing

Comment: Thanks Anton, I tried the minimal iso (mini.iso, 55mb) option with a usb, it is freezing after I select any option for installation.